Film on Ch 4 in mid 80s: Teenage boy runs away by stealing fathers car and meets girl, she has baby
This film was on Ch 4 in about 1984-85. Based in France I think. 
Rich kid steals fathers car and runs away. Ends up with a young girl living in a cottage.  He gets some fish by waiting for the fishermen to leave the small fish that wont sell (there were 3 small ones).  The boy and girl are hungry.  They end up having sex and she gets pregnant. He gets himself on his feet and gets a job picking and spraying grapes. He buys a childish book about pregnancy and birth and the girl has the baby.  They bring the baby up and have are having a very happy time if it.
At the end the boy is found by his father /people representing his father, who are looking for him and they drag him in to a car and speed away. That's the way it ends!

What is "Ch 4"?

@NapoleonWilson, probably the UKs Channel4 TV channel

How old did this film look like when you saw it? Was it in color?

When channel 4 first broadcast, in 1983, they had a branch called channel 4 films, which later became film 4. Channel 4 films often made drama/arthouse/black comedy type films. They also collaborated with studio canal, French distributor, on several films in their early days.

Pretty confident that this is Friends from 1971, where a British rich boy in Paris meets a French girl and they run away together to the idyllic French countryside, settling in a cottage. They try to play "house" as she gets pregnant and he gets a job at a vineyard, and they live quite happily after their baby is born, but in the end, the police comes and takes the boy back to his family (against his will). This film featured a soundtrack by Elton John and also had a sequel taking place 3 years later. Here are some DVD clips, where you can see the girl fishing at the start and the boy reading a basic book about birth at 3:36:




Elton John's soundtrack is one of my favorites.  I can listen to it over and over.
